# Undergrad Research for Online Students in Math?

Tags: mathematics, research-undergraduate, online-degree

I’m looking for research projects that I could join as an undergrad in mathematics. I’m going to a school that is more well known in the UK but not as well known here in the US. It would be cool if there was open source or crowd sourced math research projects and I think that would be something interesting to put on a resume given you actually do a portion of work. But are there any options for someone like me going to an online school at a non-notable university?

Comment: Are you going to The Open University?

Comment: @edelweiss Yes I am.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that, as a student at Open University, you have tutors for your classes; someone you can interact with. Present this issue to one of them and ask for help.

They may not be able to help you directly, but should be able to pass your request up the line to the professor responsible for the course. Those professors are well connected (worldwide) and might be willing to find you someone to work with.

Your tutor would need to give a good recommendation for you, of course.

I know some of the CS folks there and am pretty sure they would respond well to such a request in their own field. And they have the worldwide contacts to make it happen.

---

Caveat: My information is quite old now. I hope the local tutor system is still in place. And for other online systems this advice might not be feasible but I'd guess it would be similar at FernUniversität in Hagen, Germany.